# Laravel loop through set of input arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a design like this,

[image]

In controller I am having this code,

```
$initials   =  $request->customer_initial;
$firstnames =  $request->room_customerfirstname;
$lastnames  =  $request->room_customerlastname;

print_r($initials);
print_r($firstnames);
print_r($lastnames);
```

It give result as below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mr
    [1] => Ms
)
Array
(
    [0] => Jeffrey
    [1] => Taylor
)
Array
(
    [0] => Way
    [1] => Otwell
)
```

But what i want is like this in array format or collection format:

```
Mr Jeffrey Way
Mr Taylor Otwell
```

How can I get result like this?

Comment: Build a function that concats the data based on the array key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everyone knows but `array_map` has a feature:

```
// pass NULL as a callback and
print_r(array_map(null, $initials, $firstnames, $lastnames));
```

Another approach is to rename fields on your form, so as every group of fields describes a person.

```
<input name="customer[1][initials]" />
<input name="customer[1][first_name]" />
<input name="customer[1][last_name]" />

<input name="customer[2][initials]" />
<input name="customer[2][first_name]" />
<input name="customer[2][last_name]" />

// etc.
```

But in this case you need to control indexes `1,2,3..` manually, because just adding `[]` will not work.

Comment: To expand on that, to get the full names using collections, OP could do e.g. `collect(array_map(...))->map->implode(' ')`